# How auto-subscribe on new IMAP folders in Gnus?

Tags: emacs, imap, gnus

I need automatically subscribe on new IMAP folders created by my IMAP server in Gnus. How to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could fix the value of [`gnus-auto-subscribed-groups`](http://gnus.org/manual/gnus_9.html#SEC9) so that it includes the `nnimap` backend as well as the other mail backends. You might run into difficulties if your IMAP server does something funny like present all of your home directory as mailboxes (think I'm joking? try [uw-imapd](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.mail.imap/browse_thread/thread/b9fcacafc53ff534)); then maybe setting [`nnimap-list-pattern`](http://gnus.org/manual/gnus_210.html#SEC210) will help.

Oh, and if you don't see your newly subscribed groups, it could be because Gnus auto-subscribes groups at the [zombie level](http://gnus.org/manual/gnus_24.html#SEC24), meaning that they are not really very subscribed. Fix that by setting [`gnus-subscribe-newsgroup-method`](http://gnus.org/manual/gnus_8.html#SEC8). Gnus is like that; you really can't avoid studying the manual.